# Added Row in Datatable not shown?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datatable, dataset

I've a simple code, here I add a row to my a datatable which is in my dataset:

```
 DigiLocalDataSet dataset = new DigiLocalDataSet();

 DataRow newClientsRow = dataset.Tables["clients"].NewRow();

 newClientsRow ["clientnr"] = "123";
 newClientsRow ["name"] = "Pascal";
 newClientsRow ["city"] = "London";

 dataset.Tables["clients"].Rows.Add(newClientRow);

 clientsTableAdapter.Fill(dataset.clients);

 this.DataContext = dataset.clients.DefaultView;
```

But I don't see the inserted row in my datagrid, I see only the existing rows of the 'clients' table.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to TableAdapter.Fill is filling your 'clients' DataTable with data retrieved from your data source, so you're losing the record you manually added to the DataTable.

Comment: That is only true if ClearBeforeFill is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `clientsAdapter.ClearBeforeFill` is set to `true`. Set it to `false` or call `Fill()` on the `Clients` table before adding the new row.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
 newClientsRow.BeginEdit();
 newClientsRow ["clientnr"] = "123";
 newClientsRow ["name"] = "Pascal";
 newClientsRow ["city"] = "London";
 newClientsRow.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the command but you need to post this row.

Answer (score 0):

Did you accept changes to the dataset before refilling?  fill pulls data from the store.

Comment: I want the row directly added to the store, how can I do that?

Comment: I have not used the DigiLocalDataSet but will assume it functions much like the standard DataSet with enhancements.  With that in mind, you would call dataset.AcceptChanges() after you finish making your changes then call your tableadapter.Fill() to refresh the dataset with the new information.